# data array is dropped if the column is null or empty in Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My table contains columns with null values. But when I try to retrieve the data set in to a variable,data array is dropped if the column is null or empty.

lets say as I have 4 columns

```
[cid] => 357
[smcoordinator] => 
[title] => Null
[cname] => Maddox Adam  Portland
```

And my function is,

```
function getValue($data){

      $dataset = $data['dataset']['result_set'];
      print_r($dataset);

      //somecode...
}
```

resut in the print_r

```
[cid] => 357
[smcoordinator] => 
[cname] => Maddox Adam  Portland
```

How can I get the Null column to my dataset?

Comment: What kind of database are you using and what library are you using to access it?

Comment: I am using codeignitor and my controller passes the resulted dataset to the view, and inside view I call to the helper. This function is inside the helper. If that is what you asked.

Comment: this is not normal behavior. there must be something (in you ORM perhaps) that is filtering the nulls out.

Comment: yes thanx for the clue. My SQL filtering issue. I figure it out. :)       if(isset($k->title)){ $out[$ix]['title'] = $k->title; }                                   I removed the if statement. Now works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing  NULL with something else

```
$dataset = $data['dataset']['result_set'];
$Title = $dataset['title'];

//if title has no value give it one 
if (!$Title)
{
  $Title = "No Value";
}
```

then rebuild your result set array

```
$data['dataset']['result_set']['title'] = $Title;
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: <p>Severity: Notice</p>
    <p>Message:  Undefined index: title</p>
    <p>Filename: helpers/cigen_helper.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 42</p>

Comment: Try add static data and test your algorithm if it inserts the data with a problem then it your actual SQL statement that needs attention

Comment: Ok I sort it out. Yes. My problem is with the filtering of my SQL statement. It rejects the null values.

Comment: if(isset($k->title)){
                             $out[$ix]['title'] = $k->title;
                             
                         }

Answer (score 1):

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: title
>
> Filename: helpers/cigen_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 42
>
> –
>   user2006282 3 mins ago

Ok in MYSQL itself check that the title column is not a key column or index column as these columns cannot be null and make sure NOT NULL is not ticked

And that SQL error tells you its looking for an Index

Comment: Ok thanx. I figure it out. :)